# Doctrine one to many unable to do cascade persist because id is not provided by Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I have an Issue entity and this can have multiple Notes, the Issue Entity looks somewhat like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Note", mappedBy="issue", cascade={"persist"})
 */
 protected $notes;

 public function __construct(){
   $this->notes = new ArrayCollection();
 }
 public function getMostRecentNote(){
     $count = count($this->notes);
     if($count){
         return $this->notes[$count-1];
     }
     return "No notes";
 }
 public function getNotes(){
     return $this->notes;
 }

 public function addNote(Note $note){
     $this->notes[] = $note;
 }
 //add an auto not when status changes
 public function setStatus($status){
    if($status === $this->status){
        return;
    }
    $note = new Note();
    $note->setNote_date(new \DateTime());
    $note->setNote("Status changed from "
      .$this->status
      ." to ".$status);
    $note->setIssue($this);
    $this->addNote($note);
    $this->status=$status;
}
```

The Note looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Issue", inversedBy="notes", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="issue_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
 protected $issue;
```

When I change the status I get the following error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO issue_notes
>   (issue_id, note, note_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params
>   {"1":null,"2":"Status changed from reported to in
>   process","3":"2014-06-20 11:14:43"}:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'issue_id' cannot be null

I've found several questions about this regarding one-to-one relationships but as far as I can see the column names are correct and inverseby as well as mappedby are there.

**[solved]**

Problem was in the Note getters and setters for issue:

```
public function getIssue()
{
    return $this->issue;
}
public function setIssue($issue)
{
    $this->issue=$issue;
}
```

the setter was `$this->issues`, changed it to the code as above. Of course because Note is the owning side and determines the update I have to set the issue for the note: `$note->setIssue($this);` (added the line in the code above). Now if I create a new issue I don't have to explicitly set the ussue_id of the note (I don't know it yet before persisting). Have not tried yet creating a new issue with a note but sure it'll work.

**[update]**

Almost immediately ran in the following error `[Semantical Error] ... Doctrine Class Note has no association named issue_id`. I assumed by setting the relation between Note and Issue doctrine would be able to figure out that Note as a field called issue_id but it doesn't. Had to add the following to Note:

```
/**
 * @var integer $issue_id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="issue_id", type="integer")
 *
 */
protected $issue_id;
```

Now I can run a dql like: `SELECT n FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Note n n.issue_id = ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the add() method in doctrine collection in detail but I think the problem is that you are using array access in the add note method. If you instead use `$this->notes->add($note)` it should work since you've set cascade persist.  You could also manually set the issue id either when creating the note, or in addNote() before adding to the array/collection.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Note is indeed the owning side so need to set issue to the note (no need to set the id) `$note->setIssue($this)` Not tested yet with a newly created issue that doesn't have an id but Doctrine should be able to figure it out when persisting.